# Create a reusable/global var from EventListener in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, event-listener

I use an EventListener which checks permissions of Users accessing each controller and log those actions. I now want to add a unique identifier for each call and add it to the log. 
While that is easy INSIDE the EventListener, is there a way to use the same `$var` that was created in the EventListener in the Controller that called the EventListener?

Example:

> User accesses Controller::Something --> EventListener gets called
>   unique `$uid` gets created --> use that `$uid` inside of the
>   controller again.

My EventListener:

```
public function onKernelController(FilterControllerEvent $event)
{
   $uid = rand();
   ...
   /* Log Action */
   $this->log->writeLog('SOME MESSAGE', __LINE__, 3, $uid);
   ...
}
```

My Controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/admin/_ajax/_saveNewClient", name="saveNewClient")
 */
public function saveNewClientAction(Request $request)
{
    //DO STH
    ...
    /* Log Action */
    $this->get('log')->writeLog(
     'OTHER MESSAGE AFTER EVENTLISTENER', __LINE__, 1, $uid); //$uid from EventListener
    ...
}
```

Comment: what about a session var?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use session :

```
$session = new Session();
$session->start();

// set and get session attributes
$session->set('LINE', 'value');
$session->get('LINE');
```

Comment: No need to start the session, `$session = $request->getSession();` did the trick though. Thanks